# Webhook registration in a custom Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I'm trying to register and use a webhook programmatically. When creating the webhook and trying to register it via the API (in the Attach tab), the initial server message looks like this:

```
{
  "realtimeapi_code": "KTTqE"
}
```

At that point, I always receive an error "The Callback URL {webhook.url} has not been implemented". According to the docs, the webhook response must contain a header with the "realtimeapi_code" value. How can this be done?
[API docs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqjFL.png)

Comment: you have tagged the question with **integromat**, it would still help to indicate that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 2 modules. ONe with Webhook itself where you are calling URL and the next one connected as Webhook response, where you would output whatever you need Webhook response to say.